# Set div height before image loads

Tags: html, css

This is kinda hard to explain. Ill try my best.

I have dynamic images that load in a div (think Instagram images in a feed). the images expand or shrink with the size of the screen (responsive). I have the width set to 100% and the height is auto. The problem is the div height is nothing until the image loads than the div expands with the image. I would like it if the div (Box this image is in) was set on page load to the correct height before the image even begins to download/fill the div. Desired result would look like; on page load you have a feed of boxes that are all set to the right size then the images fill those boxes when they load.

My div css is :

```
padding: 0 10px 0 8px;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

My image css is:

```
width: 100%;
height: auto;
border-radius: 18px;
border: 1px solid #eeefef;
background: #eee;
```

Comment: and images ratio can differ, or we are talking about square sized images for example?

Comment: Do you know the dimensions of the image before it's loaded? You certainly need that.

Comment: I do but it also scales to the size of the screen/device that its loading on. thats why I set it to width 100%

Comment: Why not set a `min-height:1px` or something? edit: OH After reading your question again I see - you want the BOXES to already be the right size and visible on load, THEN the images load in them? What about a transition property?

Comment: Exactly! What are transition properties?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't set the div size to the image without knowing the image size. better try using a constant height and width for the div.

Comment: I cant. phone screen sizes are all too different.

Comment: For phones, use media query and set the width to 100% and let the height of the div be constant

Comment: in your example you have the banner height set. I want the height to grow with the width so its a perfect square. since I don't know the full width of the device I also don't know the height.

Comment: Try using `min-height` then: https://jsfiddle.net/8zfoh63q/. When the image is not added, the div retains to `min-height` and grows with the image, if the images is larger than min-height

Comment: Yeah I guess min-height will work for now. I was hoping there was a solution that would set the exact height but maybe that solution doesn't exist.